# is java.util.UUID thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am asking this question because of following observations

1. getting this stack trace in thread dump in highly multi threaded environment

   ```
    "http-80-200" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00002aaab4981000 nid=0x7520 waiting \
     for monitor entry [0x000000004fec7000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
        at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:433)
        - waiting to lock <0x00000000c00da220> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
        at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:162)
   ```
2. found this link

   https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6611830

if UUID is not thread safe, please suggest any other library if it exist.

Comment: The fact that a thread is in the `BLOCKED` state does, in itself, not mean that there is a problem. This is normal if a thread is waiting to obtain a lock for a synchronized method or code block. Only if the thread stays in this state forever could mean that there is a deadlock.

Comment: + 1 for the link (bug report by Josh Bloch...) - and by the way as linked in the bug report (http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mduigou/6611830/webrev.0/webrev/) the bug should be fixed by now

Answer (score 17):

UUID is immutable so it's potentially thread safe, but apparently there was some [evil caching going on](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6611830) in some accessors that made it unsafe (that bug is fixed now).

But your thread dump just says that a thread is waiting for a lock at `SecureRandom.nextBytes`, which is used by the `UUID.randomUUID` factory, which definitely *is* thread-safe. It's what's supposed to happen when several threads call it simultaneously, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The use of SecureRandom will make this method very slow under some circumstances.  It is good to use this source of bits if you really want the best bits, but if you want many UUID's (for a simulation perhaps), this could be disastrously slow.

Comment: As the bug was fixed years ago, should this answer say it's now thread safe?

Comment: Seems to be thread safe in Java 11 at least. You can investigate implementation in java.security.SecureRandom where method nextBytes() is the one that adds synchronization if it is not enabled in underlying random number generator.