# Enforcing a unique id in a class

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier

Just for the sake of a thought exercise, how could the uniqueness of an attribute be enforced for each instance of a given class ?

Uniqueness here can be defined as being on a single JVM and within a single user session.

This is at Java-level and not to do with databases, the main purpose being to verify if a collision has occurred.

The first obvious step is to have a static attribute at class level.

- Having an ArrayList or other container seems impractical as the number of instances rises.
- Incrementing a numeric counter at class level appears to be a simplest approach but the id must always follow the last-used-id.
- Enforcing a hash or non-numeric id could be problematic.
- Concurrency might be of concern. If it is possible for two instances get an id at the same time then this should be prevented.

How should this problem be tackled ? What solutions/approaches might already exist ?

Comment: Without specifying the scope of "uniqueness" this question is unanswerable, which is why I suspect someone voted to close.  Define what you mean by uniqueness, both in space and time.  I.e. unique in a single JVM invocation, across all space and time, or something inbetween.

Comment: Thanks for requesting a clarification @JimGarrison. Uniqueness here is about having no two values that are the same. The question is about the cases of both numeric and non-numeric values. This is within the context of the same JVM and during a user session (of undefined duration but let's say it is typical) with a desktop application or on a web site. Intuition says that larger scopes could be accommodated by reusing the "local" approach so this is the focus of the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you care about performance, here is a thread safe, fast (lock-free) and collision-free version of unique id generation

```
    public class Test {
        private static AtomicInteger lastId = new AtomicInteger();
        private int id;

        public Test() {
            id = lastId.incrementAndGet();
        }
...
```

Comment: This is not meaningful without understanding the OP's definition of uniqueness, which he has not provided so far.

Comment: @JimGarrison Uniqueness as no two values being the same. The question is about about numeric and non-numeric values. Will add to the question above.

Comment: No two values being the same in what context? A single JVM? A cluster? All JVMs for all time?

Comment: @JimGarrison Responding above :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `UUID` class in Java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html. Create a field of the type UUID in the classes under inspection and initialize this field in the constructor.

```
public class Test  {
   public UUID id;
   public Test() {
      id = UUID.randomUUID();
   }
}
```

When it comes time for detecting collisions, simply compare the string representations of the UUIDs of the objects like this ...

```
Test testObject1 = new Test();
Test testObject2 = new Test();
boolean collision = testObject1.id.toString().equals(testObject2.id.toString());
```

Or more simply use the `compareTo()` method in the `UUID` class ...

`boolean collision = testObject2.id.compareTo(testObject1.id) == 0 ? true : false;`

0 means that the `id`s are the same. +1 and -1 when they are not equal.

Merit: universally unique (can be time based, random) and hence should takes care of threading issues (some one should confirm this ... this is based off the best of my knowledge). more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) and [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).

To make it thread-safe refer to this question on SO [is java.util.UUID thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212635/is-java-util-uuid-thread-safe)

Demerit: will require a change in the structure of the classes under inspection, i.e. the `id` field will have to added in the source of the classes themselves. which might or might not be convenient.

Comment: Why waste time converting to string representations? `UUID` implements `equals()` and `Comparable<UUID>`.

Comment: @vijay Thank you for adding a statement to verify collisions :)

Comment: what's the purpose of `compareTo` when you can just use `equals`?

Comment: these are two different methods of doing the same thing. not sure of the trade-offs. So i added both to my answer. one might be better wrt  performance than the other. i would guess that converting to strings and using the equal will be not fare as well when it comes to performance. Also, `compareTo()` just looks a lot cleaner ... one method call against three.

Comment: Seems it is.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212635/is-java-util-uuid-thread-safe

Comment: i reference a different [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212635/is-java-util-uuid-thread-safe) that answers that exact question. check the updated answer ...

Comment: UUID already has an equals method, you can just write `boolean collision = o1.id.equals(o2.id)`

Comment: @DenisTulskiy yeah ... i saw that but i am not clear on if this `equals` refers to the actual unique ID held by the different UUID objects or the different UUID object references themselves. i think it is for the UUID references. i might be wrong.

Comment: @vijay I think UUID is immutable. Unless mistaken, that would mean you can use equals without any issues.

Answer (score 2):

UUID is a good solution, but UUID.randomUUID() on the backend use method:

```
synchronized public void SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[] bytes)
```

So this is slow: threads lock a single monitor object in each id generation operation.

The AtomicInteger is better, because it loops in a CAS operation. But again, for each id generation operation a synchronization operation must be done.

In the solution below, only prime numbers generation is synchronized. Synchronization is on a volatile int, so is fast and thread-safe. Having a set of primes, many ids are generated in a iteration.

## Fixed number of threads

**Edit: Solution for fixed number of thread**

I you know apriory how many threads will use the Id generation, then You can generate IDs with values

```
Id = I mod X + n*X
```

Where X is the number of threads, I is the thread number, and N is a local variable that is incremented for each Id generation. The code for this solution is really simple, but it must be integrated with the hole program infrastructure.

## Ids generated from primes

The idea is to generate the ids as factors of prime numbers
    id = p_1^f1 * p_2^f2 * p_2^f3 * ... * p_n^fn

We use different prime numbers in each thread to generate different sets of ids in each thread.

Assuming that we use primes (2,3,5), the sequence will be:

```
2, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5,..., 2^64
```

Then, when we see that a overflow will be generated, we roll the factor to the next prime:

```
3, 2*3 , 2^2*3, 2^3*3, 2^4*3, 2^5*3,..., 2^62*3
```

and next

```
3^2, 2*3^2 , 2^2*3^2, .....
```

## Generation class

**Edit: primer order generation must be done on AtomicInteger to be correct**

Each instance of class IdFactorialGenerator will generate different sets of ids.

To have a thread save generation of Ids, just use ThreadLocal to have a per-thread instance setup. Synchronization is realized only during prime number generation.

```
package eu.pmsoft.sam.idgenerator;

public class IdFactorialGenerator {
    private static AtomicInteger nextPrimeNumber = 0;

    private int usedSlots;
    private int[] primes = new int[64];
    private int[] factors = new int[64];
    private long id;
    public IdFactorialGenerator(){
        usedSlots = 1;
        primes[0] = Sieve$.MODULE$.primeNumber(nextPrimeNumber.getAndAdd(1));
        factors[0] = 1;
        id = 1;
    }

    public long nextId(){
        for (int factorToUpdate = 0; factorToUpdate < 64; factorToUpdate++) {
            if(factorToUpdate == usedSlots) {
                factors[factorToUpdate] = 1;
                primes[factorToUpdate] = Sieve$.MODULE$.primeNumber(nextPrimeNumber.getAndAdd(1));
                usedSlots++;
            }
            int primeToExtend = primes[factorToUpdate];
            if( primeToExtend < Long.MAX_VALUE / id) {
                // id * primeToExtend < Long.MAX_VALUE
                factors[factorToUpdate] = factors[factorToUpdate]*primeToExtend;
                id = id*primeToExtend;
                return id;
            } else {
                factors[factorToUpdate] = 1;
                id = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < usedSlots; i++) {
                    id = id*factors[i];
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("I can not generate more ids");
    }
}
```

To get the prime numbers I use a implementations on scala provided here in the problem 7: http://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/

```
object Sieve {

  def primeNumber(position: Int): Int = ps(position)

  private lazy val ps: Stream[Int] = 2 #:: Stream.from(3).filter(i =>
    ps.takeWhile(j => j * j <= i).forall(i % _ > 0))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code has been added just in case your site becomes unavailable.